# QMake generating weird paths in makefile

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

I'm using Qt 5.1.1 and running qmake on windows.

I run qmake with the following command:

```
qmake.exe -spec win32-msvc2012 -tp vc project.pro
```

Somehow in my makefile it generates some weird relative paths:

```
INCPATH = -I"..\..\..\qt\qwt-6.1.0\src"
```

for example.

My includepaths in the .pro file are the following:

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
$$PWD \
$$QWTDIR \
```

what did I do wrong? (The compiler searches for ......\ which it isn't allowed to access for sure)

qwtdir is defined as:

```
QWTDIR = C:/qt/qwt-6.1.0/src
```

Comment: Ok, what is the exact problem? You say you did something wrong. What are the error messages? Is there a problem?

Comment: I get an error message while compiling with MSVC2012: error C1083: Cannot open source file: '..\..\..': Permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the error. Someone committed corrupted .pri file which didn't contain a proper line break after an include i.e.:

```
HEADERS += \
$$PWD/file1.h \ $$PWD/file2.h
```

Adding a proper line break solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD` is most likely unnecessary.

Your `$$QWTDIR` is relative, most likely - you'd need to relent and show it to us. Use `$$absolute_path($${QWTDIR})`.

You could also probably put the include paths all on one line. The trailing line continuation in the last line of INCLUDEPATH is *wrong*, you must remove it:

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
$$PWD \
$$QWTDIR
```

Comment: qmake also does this with: -I"..\..\..\qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012\include" which i didn't specified for myself in the .pro file

Comment: It needs to include its own files, no problem with that. I believe that your makefile is correct. Remember that all of the paths are relative to the build directory where the Makefile is generated.

Comment: I have to run qmake a bit "ugly". like: C:\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\PROJECT>C:\qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012\bin\qmake.exe. You mean this is the problem?

Comment: That's fine, except that you're building in your sources, and that's not advised. Create an empty folder and do: C:\PROJECT_BUILD> C:\qt\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012\bin\qmake.exe C:\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\PROJECT\project.pro

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to build against the source tree of Qwt ( probably copying the project files of the Qwt examples ) instead of installing Qwt properly and building against the installed version using:

CONFIG += qwt

See http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html